# About determining the level id value (user defined field["level_id"]) of a record in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Can somebody help me with this code. I can't figure out how to exactly put the value of 1 starting at the 5th record at the level_id field. It always remains as 0 then the 6th record is started as 1.

```
    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_EncodePerson`(
    in p_memberId varchar(45),
    in p_encodeId varchar(100))

    BEGIN

    DECLARE Lev0 varchar(5);
    DECLARE Lev1 varchar(5);

    SET Lev0 = "0";
    SET Lev1 = "1";

    SELECT @total := count(*) from gph_acquiredpeople 
    where member_Id = p_memberId;

IF @total <= 4 THEN 
    INSERT INTO gph_acquiredpeople
    (member_id,encoded_mem_Id,date_encoded,level_id)
    VALUES (p_memberId,p_encodeId,NOW(),Lev0);
    UPDATE gph_memberstatus SET available ="0", taken = "1"
    WHERE Id_number = p_encodeId;

ELSEIF @total = 5 OR @total >= 5 AND @total < 25 THEN
    INSERT INTO gph_acquiredpeople
    (member_id,encoded_mem_Id,date_encoded,level_id)
    VALUES (p_memberId,p_encodeId,NOW(),Lev1);
    UPDATE gph_memberstatus SET available ="0", taken = "1"
    WHERE Id_number = p_encodeId;        
ELSE
    BEGIN        
    END;
END IF;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well your issue, the solution seems pretty simple:

As you're doing the @total count check before inserting your record, you have to compare @total with (the record number you want to start inserting with Lev1) - 1. With your current check, when @total = 4, you keep inserting with Lev0, and it'll be your... 5th record.

So it would be:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_EncodePerson`(
    in p_memberId varchar(45),
    in p_encodeId varchar(100))

    BEGIN

    DECLARE Lev0 varchar(5);
    DECLARE Lev1 varchar(5);

    SET Lev0 = "0";
    SET Lev1 = "1";

    SELECT @total := count(*) from gph_acquiredpeople 
    where member_Id = p_memberId;

IF @total < 4 THEN 
    INSERT INTO gph_acquiredpeople
    (member_id,encoded_mem_Id,date_encoded,level_id)
    VALUES (p_memberId,p_encodeId,NOW(),Lev0);
    UPDATE gph_memberstatus SET available ="0", taken = "1"
    WHERE Id_number = p_encodeId;

ELSEIF @total >= 4 AND @total < 25 THEN
    INSERT INTO gph_acquiredpeople
    (member_id,encoded_mem_Id,date_encoded,level_id)
    VALUES (p_memberId,p_encodeId,NOW(),Lev1);
    UPDATE gph_memberstatus SET available ="0", taken = "1"
    WHERE Id_number = p_encodeId;        
ELSE
    BEGIN        
    END;
END IF;
END
```

Comment: Thanks, for the solution. I'll try it by next week since I'm already out of work.

Comment: Sir, what if not against the record number. Purely, record count. Is there any way?

Comment: I don't understand perfectly what you want. Change your check with `@total` which is actually done with record count, in order to check record number instead?

Comment: No sir. What I want is when the record count hits 5 level_id field will be inserted with a value of 1. Actually, the script is not yet finished. It has 10 levels and the record counting is multiplied by 5. Well, I have already solved it. Since changing the condition of total <=3. Yes, the 5th record level_id field was changed to 1. What I don't understand is why the inserting done when the condition of total is <= to 3?

Comment: Corrections, I mean total > 3.

Comment: Starting from the 5th record, level_id field value is equal to 1. Then, when record count is equal to 25 and record count < 25, level value = 2, so on and so on.

Comment: Sorry but I don't get it... "when record count is equal to 25 and record count < 25": how is that possible ?